# Visual Studio not opening TypeScript *.ts files?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017

When I try to open a TypeScript file, my cursor goes busy for a bit, then nothing happens; the code window doesn't open.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd installed the Qt Visual Studio Tools extension for Visual Studio 2017. This associated *.ts files with the QT Linguist file format and editor.

To fix the problem, I right-clicked a *.ts file, navigated to the Open With dialog, and defaulted TypeScriptEditor as the program to open the file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fix! Was having the same issue, and thought the only solution was to disable the Qt extension.